# How can I anticipate which type of CSS selector will work?

Tags: css, dojo

I'm creating a form with dojo, and I want a range-restricted number input field.  So I use this:

```
<input 
    id             = "sample_input"
    type           = "text"
    dojoType       = "dijit.form.NumberTextBox"
    name           = "sample_input"
    value          = "27"
    constraints    = "{min:1,max:30,places:0}"
    promptMessage  = "Enter a value"
    required       = "true" 
    invalidMessage = "Invalid value."
/>
```

It works, but it is too wide, and the content is left-justified.

Neither of these lines, added to my INPUT element, appears to make a difference:

```
width              = "60"
text-align         = "right"
```

which is a question in and of itself, but that's OK, I know I should be using CSS instead of HTML.  So I add this in the HEAD section:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .NARROW {width:60px;}
    .RIGHT_JUSTIFIED {text-align:right;}
</style>
```

and this to the INPUT element:

```
class              = "NARROW RIGHT_JUSTIFIED"
```

and that solves the width, but not the text justification.

To solve the text justification, I must instead do this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .NARROW {width:60px;}
    input {text-align:right;}
</style>
```

Specifying the `width` property in the `input` style doesn't work, either.

So that's my question.  Why don't inline styles work in this case, and why must I use a class selector for width, but an element selector for text-align?  And how can I anticipate when which selector will be applicable?

Comment: You have a - (dash) in your class attribute, but a _ (underscore) in your css selector. Is that a typo in your post here, or the way your code is actually written?

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo and I have corrected it.  The code did not have this error (it doesn't change the text alignment when the class name matches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried this code and it seems to work fine

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

    .width_narrow {width:60px;}
    .align_right {text-align:right;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<input
    name           = "sample_input"
    type           = "text" 
    class         = "width_narrow align_right" 
    id             = "sample_input"
    value          = "27"
    dojoType       = "dijit.form.NumberTextBox"
    constraints    = "{min:1,max:30,places:0}"
    promptMessage  = "Enter a value"
    required       = "true" 
    invalidMessage = "Invalid value."
/>

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I use it alone like that, it works for me as well.  My screen doesn't stand alone, however; it's embedded in a "navigation" as part of the apache turbine framework - and I think you've pointed me to what might be the source of the problem.  If I take my HTML out of its context, it's OK.  So I need to see what in the context is messing with it.  I tried, with this question, to isolate the problem, but in doing so lost the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your class selector.

RIGHT_JUSTIFIED and RIGHT-JUSTIFIED will not match

Comment: Thank you; this typo has been corrected, but does not affect the curious behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if there is a more specific selector overriding `.RIGHT_JUSTIFIED`.

Comment: Thank you; FireBug tells me that my RIGHT_JUSTIFIED class is the operative specification and that the text-align is therefore "right" - but my eyes tell me otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If a selector isn't working, there are a couple quick tests you can do to isolate the problem.

First, I try trying a more specific selector to see if a selector in a different part of the CSS is overriding your styles. For example,

```
body #problem { ... }
```

is more specific than

```
#problem { ... }
```

You can also add the !important property, which gives the property precedence over [nearly] all other properties, no matter how much more specific they are:

```
#problem { width:60px !important; }
```

If neither of those works, there's either a deeper issue, or a sneaky typo. At this stage, completely isolating the section of HTML and CSS (as you've done in the answer above) is the most effective, but also more time consuming.